# Chrome - open links within the same domain in the same tab

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I have a few pinned tabs in Chrome (v16.0.912.63 m) namely www.bbc.co.uk/news. When I click on links within the BBC News website (e.g., http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-16358064), the link opens in a new tab. This behavior is extremely annoying as a 15 minute browsing sessions ends up spawning multiple tabs that need to be closed individually. Links within the same domain in unpinned tabs open within the same tab as expected.

I want links within the same domain to open in the same tab (pinned or unpinned) and links pointing to external sites opening in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the "Open PinnedTab Link" Chrome extension with the settings below and restarting the browser helped to solve this problem. Links clicked within the same domain inside a pinned tab open in the same tab whereas external links open in a new tab.

- Enabled: Clicked links will open in new tabs. - OFF
- Outbound Links Only: Keep links to the same domain in the pinned tab. - ON

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's still interested, I made an extension that accomplishes this‒ "New Domain in New Tab" supports whitelists/blacklists on a per-domain basis, so you can fine-tune which sites it is enabled/disabled for.

Find it on the Chrome store:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-domain-in-new-tab/nokdeeoiaiicgnonknihiccadnnmpeoh